# Why view doesn't listen model events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

I have a basic model such as:

```
    define(['backbone', 'relational'], function(Backbone, Relational) {
        var resultEntityModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
            defaults : {
                bgOccurence : "",
                fgOccurence : "",
            },
            initialize : function() {                   
                var bgOccurence = this.set("bgOccurence",this.get("bgOccurence"));       
                var fgOccurence = this.set("fgOccurence",this.get("fgOccurence"));
            }
        });

        return resultEntityModel;
    });
```

And a view:

```
define(['marionette', 'js/models/result/result.entity.model', 'text!templates/result/result.entity.panel.html'], function(Marionette, ResultEntityModel, ResultEntityPanel) {
    var resultEntityView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        tagName : "tr",
        template : ResultEntityPanel,
        initialize: function () {
            this.model.on("change:fgOccurence", function() { console.log("hello"); });
      }                      
    });
    return resultEntityView;
});
```

But this code doesn't print hello to console. I couldn't find the problem but i'm pretty sure view doesn't listen change event but why? Thanks for help.

Comment: your model is already initialized by the time you come to initialize of the view. Try writing the `this.model.set("value")` before `this.model.on("change:fgOccurence",...` this line and check.

Comment: Maby i can call a function from view's initialize function which listens model change events always. But how can i do that? For example  this.listenTo(this.model, "change:bgOccurence", this....); is not working in view. It gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listen To'

Comment: the job of listening to change is done by `on` function, but since you are initializing that listener in the iniialize method of your view, you will have to trigger that event after that to know that its working.....

Comment: u dont have to manually set attributes to the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When u are passing the model to the view, it is already initialized, attributes set, change events triggered.
Try to create an instance of the model (didnt used requirejs syntax, just a pseudo code based on local variables):

```
var model = new resultEntityModel();
var view = new resultEntityView({model: model});
model.set('bgOccurence', 'new value to bg');
```

And now u can see the console log.